# Which Distro provides Timely Security Updates and have the longest support cycle for Raspberry Pi 1,2 & 3?

Tags: linux, update, security

I am looking for a Linux Distro that provides timely security updates for all Raspberry Pi variants.  Please indicate if the update life-cycle is released based (preferred) or rolling/continuous. Indicate the support time frame / length.

Please focus on Distros provide Long Term Support distros.  Also I am not after specialist Distros like OSMC.  I am after a general purpose Distro.

Comment: Far too broad for this site.  You really need to do your own research.

Comment: I did, but was surprised that there are no LTS for RPi 1/Rpi 0 particularly, but I was hoping I may have missed something.  Unfortunately most literature on RPi seems to be aimed at hobby/newby/non production uses, so security is an afterthought!.   Right now for RPi 1 its seems I am back to Raspbian, but LTS updates seem to be best effort.  Arch is unofficial.  OpenSuse point releases are 18months.  No Debian or Ubuntu for RPi0/1.  FreeBSD is Tier 2 only.  CentOS no kernel, only userland.  Gentoo rolling updates.

Answer (score 1):

Raspbian is the answer. Raspbian follows Debian which has recently started a LTS program. Check the timelines [there](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS). Please note that the foundation has deprecated Raspbian versions for which the corresponding Debian version was still inside the support cycle in the past. But the foundation does monitor the health of Raspbian (and nothing else) and they continously provide feature updates for it. The security updates from Debian also follow automatically and are comfortably available via `apt-get upgrade`

Comment: Not really after feature updates, but security updates in a timely manner.

Comment: Security updates come from the recompilation of Debian updates itself. The foundation has been quite dilligent in that regard as far as i remember.